# IPython Notebook/Matplotlib: Interactive show/hide graphs on a plot, is it possible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using IPython Notebook and Matplotlib to visualise some data, with inline display mode (i.e. I want to display and interact with my plots on the web interface of IPython Notebook).

I have a plot showing several different graphs and I would like to have an interactive interface (a set of checkboxes for example) that allow me to hide or show the graphs.

My plot looks like this:

[image: Difficult to explore the 9 graphs together, better to hide some of them and show others]

I another word: I have a plot where I display many different graphs, each graph is a line and it has its own legend. I would like to add a set of check-boxes to the plot, each one for a graph. When the checkpoint is checked the graph will be visible, when unchecked the graph will disappear.

Comment: yes, this is possible. You may want to have a look at `ipywidgets`. However your question is probably too broad to be answered.

Comment: Thanks cel :) my question is: I have a plot where I plotted 9 different graphs (lines), each one has its own legend. I would like to add a set of checkboxes beside the plot (9 checkboxes), each one for one graph. When the checkpoint is checked the graph will be visible, when unchecked the graph will disappear.

Comment: `%matplotlib notebook` will give you an interactive figure you can pan/zoom.

Comment: @tcaswell that won't hide/display the individual lines that he's asking about.

Comment: @tcaswell exactly as Leb said, this will not allow me to show and hide the lines.

Comment: Didn't know you were going for inline. `ipywidgets` is indeed the best place to look for this, you could extract some inspiration from their [example](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/tree/master/examples) notebooks.

Comment: once you have a live figure, you can mutate it however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need references to the artists created by your plotting routine.  The plotting methods attached to the DataFrame objects return the `Axes` object they plotted to instead (this is useful for simple things, but makes complex things impossible) so, some plotting code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

def pandas_plot(ax, df, style_cycle, **kwargs):
    """
    Plot a pandas DataFrame

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : matplotlib.axes.Axes
        The axes to plot to

    df : pd.DataFrame
        The data to plot

    style_cycle : Cycler
        Something that when iterated over yields style dict

    Returns
    -------
    ret : dict
        Dictionary of line2d artists added 
    """
    ret = {}
    x = df.index
    for n, sty in zip(df.columns, style_cycle):
        sty.update(kwargs)
        ln, = ax.plot(x, df[n], label=n, **sty)
        ret[n] = ln
    ax.legend()
    return ret
```

Now some code to set up the widget interface (this is doing more than you asked for, but this is what I have pre-made from my scipy talk):

```
from IPython.html.widgets import *
from IPython.display import display

def widget_function_factory(arts):
    """
    Generate fulnction + args to pass to interactive
    Parameters
    ----------
    arts : dict
        dictionary of Line2D

    """

    name = Dropdown(options=list(arts.keys()))

    def set_all(_, old_line, new_line):
        ln = arts[new_line]
        lw.value = ln.get_lw()
        alph.value = ln.get_alpha() or 1
        visible.value = ln.get_visible()
        markevery.value = ln.get_markevery()
        marker.value = ln.get_marker()

    def set_lw(_, old_lw, new_lw):
        ln = arts[name.value]
        arts[name.value].set_lw(new_lw)
        arts[name.value].axes.legend()

    def set_alpha(_, old_value, new_value):
        ln = arts[name.value]
        ln.set_alpha(new_value)
        ln.axes.legend()

    def set_visible(_, old_value, new_value):
        ln = arts[name.value]
        ln.set_visible(new_value)
        ln.axes.legend()

    def set_markevery(_, old_value, new_value):
        ln = arts[name.value]
        ln.set_markevery(new_value)

    def set_marker(_, old_value, new_value):
        ln = arts[name.value]
        ln.set_marker(new_value)
        ln.axes.legend()

    lw = FloatSlider(min=1, max=5, description='lw: ')
    alph = FloatSlider(min=0, max=1, description='alpha: ')
    visible = Checkbox(description='visible: ')
    markevery = IntSlider(min=1, max=15, description='markevery: ')
    marker = Dropdown(options={v:k for k, v in matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.markers.items()},
                     description='marker: ')

    name.on_trait_change(set_all, 'value')
    lw.on_trait_change(set_lw, 'value')
    alph.on_trait_change(set_alpha, 'value')
    visible.on_trait_change(set_visible, 'value')
    markevery.on_trait_change(set_markevery, 'value')
    marker.on_trait_change(set_marker, 'value')
    display(name, lw, alph, marker, markevery, visible)
    set_all(None, None, name.value)
```

do the plotting:

```
th = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128)
df = pd.DataFrame({'sin': np.sin(th),
                   'shift +': np.sin(th + np.pi / 3), 
                   'shift -': np.sin(th - np.pi / 3)}, index=th)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
from cycler import cycler
style_cycle = cycler('color',['r', 'black', 'pink']) + cycler('marker', 'sxo')
#style_cycle = [{'color': 'r', 'marker': 's'},
#               {'color': 'black', 'marker': 'x'},
#               {'color': 'pink', 'marker': 'o'}]
arts = pandas_plot(ax, df, style_cycle, markevery=10)
vlns = []
for x in np.arange(1, 7) * np.pi/3:
    vlns.append(plt.axvline(x, color='k', linestyle=':'))
plt.axhline(0, color='k', linestyle=':')
```

and create the controls

```
widget_function_factory(arts)
```

`cycler` is a side project that spun off of mpl (and will be a required dep for 1.5).  It is currently pip installable.

See https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/7a0e5e76fb3cafa3b7cd#file-so_interactive_demo-ipynb for a demo notebook.

There is on-going work to make this easier (so that mpl Artists can auto-construct their UI elements).  The infrastructure that will make that work is one of the major goals of mpl 2.1.